# Box2DWeb, PolygonShape.SetAsVector not detect collision

Tags: vector, collision, shapes, box2dweb

Here's the prolem

[image]

If I define the baseball bat with SetAsBox the no problem.

This kind of weird happens when I define it using SetAsVector

```
this.view = new createjs.Bitmap("hammer.png");
this.view.regX = 0;
this.view.regY = 0;

var fixDef = new box2d.b2FixtureDef();
fixDef.density = 5.0;
fixDef.friction = 0.5;
fixDef.restitution = 0.8;
var bodyDef = new box2d.b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = box2d.b2Body.b2_kinematicBody;
fixDef.shape = new box2d.b2PolygonShape();
var vertices = []
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(30/SCALE, 0/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(14/SCALE, 0/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(17/SCALE, 10/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(17/SCALE, 100/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(0/SCALE, 290/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(12/SCALE, 300/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(32/SCALE, 300/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(44/SCALE, 290/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(27/SCALE, 100/SCALE));
vertices.push(new box2d.b2Vec2(27/SCALE, 10/SCALE));
fixDef.shape.SetAsVector(vertices, 10);
bodyDef.position.x = 600 / SCALE;
bodyDef.position.y = 300 / SCALE;
this.view.body =  world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
this.view.body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
```

Anyone know about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The method SetAsVector expects a convex polygon. But I think what you are trying to set here is a concave one.

Newer versions of Box2D support generating convex polygons out of a concave ones, but I don't think Box2DWeb supports this.

You can solve this by splitting your concave polygon into two convex polygons and creating two fixtures instead of one.

[Wikipedia article about convex and concave polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons)